# gRPC C++ on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2015, grpc

I have been trying for 3 days by now to find how to install and use gRPC on windows with no luck.  I am using Visual Studio 2015, Win7 64-bit. To be safe, I'll write step by step of what I am doing.  It might not be necessary but I am a beginner with C++ and with VS so I am not at all sure I am doing it correctly:

(following guide http://www.infopulse.com/blog/grpc-framework-by-google-tutorial/):

- Get gRPC from git, init submodules
- Get gmock and gtest for protobuf (not in the guide, but else it
  doesn't work)
- Run *cmake* on protobuf
- Build *protobuf.sln* in Visual Studio in Release mode (set for each part of the solution Property Manager > C/C++ > Code Generation > Runtime Library > **/MDd**)
- Copy Release/ folder to protobuf/cmake/ (instead of Debug/ as in intructions - that would give me *libprotobufd.lib* instead of *libprotobuf.lib* which is required)
- Build *grpc/vsprojects/grpc_protoc_plugins.sln* in VS also in Release mode and again set for each part of the solution Property Manager > C/C++ > Code Generation > Runtime Library > **/MDd**
- Copy *protoc.exe* from protobuf/cmake/Release to grpc/vsprojects/Release, which was created in previous step
- Build *grpc/vsprojects/grpc.sln* in VS in Debug mode (only the grpc++ part as I read somewhere and again set for each part of the solution Property Manager > C/C++ > Code Generation > Runtime Library > **/MDd**)

So far things are going well.

- Generate c files from proto in example folder. I get *helloworld.grpc.pb.cc*, *helloworld.grpc.pb.h*, *helloworld.pb.cc* and *helloworld.pb.h* and move them all to grpc/examples/cpp/helloworld:

  protoc --grpc_out=./hello_proto --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=grpc_cpp_plugin.exe ../../examples/protos/helloworld.proto --proto_path=../../examples/protos

  protoc --cpp_out=./hello_proto ../../examples/protos/helloworld.proto --proto_path=../../examples/protos
- I keep the *grpc.sln* open in VS and 'Add' > 'New Project'
- To the new project 'Add' > 'Existing Item' and add *greeter_client.cc* from grpc/examples/cpp
- Add dependencies as: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/4707 , with Includes going in C/C++ > Additional Include Directories

When I try to build my project errors are reported with not finding gflags, gtest, and libprotobuf. If I find it all and move them to an included folder, then I get these errors:

```
    1>------ Build started: Project: greeter_client, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  greeter_client.cc
1>libprotobuf.lib(generated_message_util.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in greeter_client.obj
1>libprotobuf.lib(generated_message_util.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MT_StaticRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in greeter_client.obj
1>libprotobuf.lib(common.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in greeter_client.obj
1>libprotobuf.lib(common.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MT_StaticRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in greeter_client.obj
1>libprotobuf.lib(once.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in greeter_client.obj
1>libprotobuf.lib(once.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MT_StaticRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in greeter_client.obj
1>libprotobuf.lib(status.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in greeter_client.obj
1>libprotobuf.lib(status.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MT_StaticRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in greeter_client.obj
1>libprotobuf.lib(int128.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in greeter_client.obj
1>libprotobuf.lib(int128.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MT_StaticRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in greeter_client.obj
1>libprotobuf.lib(atomicops_internals_x86_msvc.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in greeter_client.obj
1>libprotobuf.lib(atomicops_internals_x86_msvc.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MT_StaticRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in greeter_client.obj
1>grpc++.lib(client_context.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MTd_StaticDebug' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in greeter_client.obj
1>grpc++.lib(insecure_credentials.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MTd_StaticDebug' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in greeter_client.obj
1>grpc++.lib(create_channel.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MTd_StaticDebug' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in greeter_client.obj
1>grpc++.lib(credentials.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MTd_StaticDebug' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in greeter_client.obj
1>grpc++.lib(create_channel_internal.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MTd_StaticDebug' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in greeter_client.obj
1>grpc++.lib(channel_arguments.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MTd_StaticDebug' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in greeter_client.obj
1>grpc++.lib(core_codegen.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MTd_StaticDebug' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in greeter_client.obj
1>grpc++.lib(codegen_init.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MTd_StaticDebug' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in greeter_client.obj
1>grpc++.lib(status.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MTd_StaticDebug' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in greeter_client.obj
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP140D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: bool __thiscall std::ios_base::good(void)const " (?good@ios_base@std@@QBE_NXZ) already defined in grpc++.lib(channel_arguments.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP140D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: int __thiscall std::ios_base::flags(void)const " (?flags@ios_base@std@@QBEHXZ) already defined in grpc++.lib(channel_arguments.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP140D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __int64 __thiscall std::ios_base::width(void)const " (?width@ios_base@std@@QBE_JXZ) already defined in grpc++.lib(channel_arguments.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP140D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __int64 __thiscall std::ios_base::width(__int64)" (?width@ios_base@std@@QAE_J_J@Z) already defined in grpc++.lib(channel_arguments.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP140D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: int __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::sputc(char)" (?sputc@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEHD@Z) already defined in grpc++.lib(channel_arguments.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP140D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __int64 __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::sputn(char const *,__int64)" (?sputn@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAE_JPBD_J@Z) already defined in grpc++.lib(channel_arguments.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP140D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall std::basic_ios<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::setstate(int,bool)" (?setstate@?$basic_ios@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEXH_N@Z) already defined in grpc++.lib(channel_arguments.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP140D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > * __thiscall std::basic_ios<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::tie(void)const " (?tie@?$basic_ios@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QBEPAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@2@XZ) already defined in grpc++.lib(channel_arguments.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP140D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: class std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > * __thiscall std::basic_ios<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::rdbuf(void)const " (?rdbuf@?$basic_ios@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QBEPAV?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@2@XZ) already defined in grpc++.lib(channel_arguments.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP140D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: char __thiscall std::basic_ios<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::fill(void)const " (?fill@?$basic_ios@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QBEDXZ) already defined in grpc++.lib(channel_arguments.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP140D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: char __thiscall std::basic_ios<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::widen(char)const " (?widen@?$basic_ios@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QBEDD@Z) already defined in grpc++.lib(channel_arguments.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP140D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::_Osfx(void)" (?_Osfx@?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEXXZ) already defined in libprotobuf.lib(status.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP140D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __thiscall std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::flush(void)" (?flush@?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEAAV12@XZ) already defined in libprotobuf.lib(status.obj)
1>libcpmt.lib(ios.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in greeter_client.obj
1>libcpmt.lib(ios.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MT_StaticRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in greeter_client.obj
1>libcpmt.lib(ios.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: static void __cdecl std::ios_base::_Addstd(class std::ios_base *)" (?_Addstd@ios_base@std@@SAXPAV12@@Z) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP140D.dll)
1>libcpmt.lib(ios.obj) : error LNK2005: "private: static void __cdecl std::ios_base::_Ios_base_dtor(class std::ios_base *)" (?_Ios_base_dtor@ios_base@std@@CAXPAV12@@Z) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP140D.dll)
1>libcpmt.lib(locale0.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in greeter_client.obj
1>libcpmt.lib(locale0.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MT_StaticRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in greeter_client.obj
1>libcpmt.lib(locale0.obj) : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl std::_Facet_Register(class std::_Facet_base *)" (?_Facet_Register@std@@YAXPAV_Facet_base@1@@Z) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(locale0_implib.obj)
1>libcpmt.lib(locale0.obj) : error LNK2005: "private: static class std::locale::_Locimp * __cdecl std::locale::_Getgloballocale(void)" (?_Getgloballocale@locale@std@@CAPAV_Locimp@12@XZ) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP140D.dll)
1>libcpmt.lib(locale0.obj) : error LNK2005: "private: static class std::locale::_Locimp * __cdecl std::locale::_Init(bool)" (?_Init@locale@std@@CAPAV_Locimp@12@_N@Z) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP140D.dll)
1>libcpmt.lib(locale0.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: static void __cdecl std::_Locinfo::_Locinfo_ctor(class std::_Locinfo *,char const *)" (?_Locinfo_ctor@_Locinfo@std@@SAXPAV12@PBD@Z) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP140D.dll)
1>libcpmt.lib(locale0.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: static void __cdecl std::_Locinfo::_Locinfo_dtor(class std::_Locinfo *)" (?_Locinfo_dtor@_Locinfo@std@@SAXPAV12@@Z) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP140D.dll)
1>libcpmt.lib(iosptrs.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in greeter_client.obj
1>libcpmt.lib(iosptrs.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MT_StaticRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in greeter_client.obj
1>libcpmt.lib(locale.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in greeter_client.obj
1>libcpmt.lib(locale.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MT_StaticRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in greeter_client.obj
1>libcpmt.lib(xlock.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in greeter_client.obj
1>libcpmt.lib(xlock.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MT_StaticRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in greeter_client.obj
1>libcpmt.lib(xlock.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::_Lockit::_Lockit(int)" (??0_Lockit@std@@QAE@H@Z) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP140D.dll)
1>libcpmt.lib(xlock.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::_Lockit::~_Lockit(void)" (??1_Lockit@std@@QAE@XZ) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP140D.dll)
1>libcpmt.lib(xthrow.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in greeter_client.obj
1>libcpmt.lib(xthrow.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MT_StaticRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in greeter_client.obj
1>libcpmt.lib(xthrow.obj) : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl std::_Xbad_alloc(void)" (?_Xbad_alloc@std@@YAXXZ) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP140D.dll)
1>libcpmt.lib(xthrow.obj) : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl std::_Xlength_error(char const *)" (?_Xlength_error@std@@YAXPBD@Z) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP140D.dll)
1>libcpmt.lib(xthrow.obj) : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl std::_Xout_of_range(char const *)" (?_Xout_of_range@std@@YAXPBD@Z) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP140D.dll)
1>libcpmt.lib(wlocale.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in greeter_client.obj
1>libcpmt.lib(wlocale.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MT_StaticRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in greeter_client.obj
1>libcpmt.lib(xlocale.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in greeter_client.obj
1>libcpmt.lib(xlocale.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MT_StaticRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in greeter_client.obj
1>libcpmt.lib(xdateord.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in greeter_client.obj
1>libcpmt.lib(xdateord.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MT_StaticRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in greeter_client.obj
1>libcpmt.lib(xwctomb.obj) : error LNK2005: __Getcvt already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP140D.dll)
1>libcpmt.lib(winapisupp.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in greeter_client.obj
1>libcpmt.lib(winapisupp.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MT_StaticRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in greeter_client.obj
1>libcpmt.lib(StlCompareStringA.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in greeter_client.obj
1>libcpmt.lib(StlCompareStringA.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MT_StaticRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in greeter_client.obj
1>libcpmt.lib(winapinls.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in greeter_client.obj
1>libcpmt.lib(winapinls.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MT_StaticRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in greeter_client.obj
1>libcpmt.lib(StlCompareStringW.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in greeter_client.obj
1>libcpmt.lib(StlCompareStringW.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MT_StaticRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in greeter_client.obj
1>libcpmt.lib(StlLCMapStringW.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in greeter_client.obj
1>libcpmt.lib(StlLCMapStringW.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MT_StaticRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in greeter_client.obj
1>libcpmt.lib(StlLCMapStringA.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in greeter_client.obj
1>libcpmt.lib(StlLCMapStringA.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MT_StaticRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in greeter_client.obj
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMTD' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>libeay32.lib(c_zlib.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol _deflate imported in function _BIO_f_zlib
1>libeay32.lib(c_zlib.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol _deflateEnd imported in function _BIO_f_zlib
1>libeay32.lib(c_zlib.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol _inflate imported in function _BIO_f_zlib
1>libeay32.lib(c_zlib.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol _inflateEnd imported in function _BIO_f_zlib
1>libeay32.lib(c_zlib.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol _deflateInit_ imported in function _BIO_f_zlib
1>libeay32.lib(c_zlib.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol _inflateInit_ imported in function _BIO_f_zlib
1>libeay32.lib(c_zlib.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol _zError imported in function _zlib_zfree
1>greeter_client.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall helloworld::HelloRequest::HelloRequest(void)" (??0HelloRequest@helloworld@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __thiscall GreeterClient::SayHello(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?SayHello@GreeterClient@@QAE?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@ABV23@@Z)
1>greeter_client.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall helloworld::HelloRequest::~HelloRequest(void)" (??1HelloRequest@helloworld@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __thiscall GreeterClient::SayHello(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?SayHello@GreeterClient@@QAE?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@ABV23@@Z)
1>greeter_client.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall helloworld::HelloReply::HelloReply(void)" (??0HelloReply@helloworld@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __thiscall GreeterClient::SayHello(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?SayHello@GreeterClient@@QAE?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@ABV23@@Z)
1>greeter_client.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall helloworld::HelloReply::~HelloReply(void)" (??1HelloReply@helloworld@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __thiscall GreeterClient::SayHello(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?SayHello@GreeterClient@@QAE?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@ABV23@@Z)
1>greeter_client.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class grpc::Status __thiscall helloworld::Greeter::Stub::SayHello(class grpc::ClientContext *,class helloworld::HelloRequest const &,class helloworld::HelloReply *)" (?SayHello@Stub@Greeter@helloworld@@UAE?AVStatus@grpc@@PAVClientContext@5@ABVHelloRequest@3@PAVHelloReply@3@@Z) referenced in function "public: class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __thiscall GreeterClient::SayHello(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?SayHello@GreeterClient@@QAE?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@ABV23@@Z)
1>greeter_client.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class std::unique_ptr<class helloworld::Greeter::Stub,struct std::default_delete<class helloworld::Greeter::Stub> > __cdecl helloworld::Greeter::NewStub(class std::shared_ptr<class grpc::ChannelInterface> const &,class grpc::StubOptions const &)" (?NewStub@Greeter@helloworld@@SA?AV?$unique_ptr@VStub@Greeter@helloworld@@U?$default_delete@VStub@Greeter@helloworld@@@std@@@std@@ABV?$shared_ptr@VChannelInterface@grpc@@@4@ABVStubOptions@grpc@@@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall GreeterClient::GreeterClient(class std::shared_ptr<class grpc::Channel>)" (??0GreeterClient@@QAE@V?$shared_ptr@VChannel@grpc@@@std@@@Z)
1>grpc++.lib(create_channel_internal.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall grpc::Channel::~Channel(void)" (??1Channel@grpc@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual void * __thiscall grpc::Channel::`scalar deleting destructor'(unsigned int)" (??_GChannel@grpc@@UAEPAXI@Z)
1>grpc++.lib(create_channel_internal.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: __thiscall grpc::Channel::Channel(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,struct grpc_channel *)" (??0Channel@grpc@@AAE@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@PAUgrpc_channel@@@Z) referenced in function "class std::shared_ptr<class grpc::Channel> __cdecl grpc::CreateChannelInternal(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,struct grpc_channel *)" (?CreateChannelInternal@grpc@@YA?AV?$shared_ptr@VChannel@grpc@@@std@@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@3@PAUgrpc_channel@@@Z)
1>C:\Tool\C++gRPC\grpc\vsprojects\\Debug\gflagsd.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'
1>C:\Tool\C++gRPC\grpc\vsprojects\Debug\greeter_client.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 8 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

If anyone could offer a solution, I will be grateful.

Comment: ***error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2'*** I believe this means you are using a release library in a debug application.

Comment: ***LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library*** This also identifies the release CRT and debug CRT mismatch. Make sure every library / dll is built with the same configuration.

Comment: ***Build grpc/vsprojects/grpc.sln in VS in Debug mode*** Since you did the above steps in Release mode you can't do this step in Debug mode.

Comment: Thank you drescherjm. I went to beggining and built all (protobuf.sln, grpc_protoc_plugins.sln and grpc++ option in grpc.sln)  in Release. The errors dissapeared, though there is new - /ZI and /GL not compatible. I googled it and found it is some kind of debug and optimization, so I went though all the *.sln files building again with Debug Information Format (in Property Pages > C/C++ > General) and Whole Program Optimization (In Property Pages >C/C++ > Optimization) both set to None. But it does not solve it.

Comment: ***The errors dissapeared, though there is new - /ZI and /GL not compatible.*** That is probably an error that is solvable. Unlike the mixing of Debug and Release which will not work (may compile but will likely cause a crash during runtime because of the incompatible CRT).

Comment: Perfect, thank you for your help. I am going to look into this error

Comment: `It might not be necessary but I am a beginner with C` Two things: 1. more information is generally good, so kudos. We like to see what steps you've taken :) 2. C isn't C++; make sure you have the nomenclature correct!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

After struggling with various errors for many days, I found ready-to-install version here https://github.com/plasticbox/grpc-windows which seems to work satisfactory for my purpose. I post it here in case anyone is in similar situation.

**Update: June 2020**

According to the project page on GitHub the project is no longer maintained and therefore the example might not work any longer:

> May 2019 NOTE: Project is no longer under active development, I
> definitely recommend using vcpkg

Comment: After struggling with GRPC/Protobuf for a day I finally found this post and it saved my sanity. Awesome!

Comment: I didn't need to struggle, because I found these sweet scripts (thanks to this post) and I used it to build protobuf3 and grpc in Windows 10, 64bits. Thanks!

Comment: I did the same for few days then I come across this post...A star for him on github!

Comment: Attention, the script which was mentioned, builds "v1.3.x" of gRPC that is quite old and the gRPC team changed the way how to build so be carefully!!!

Comment: Look at some of the forks of the above github project if you want a version that builds a newer grpc or a version that builds with a newer version of Visual Studio.

Comment: @jonathanjg I wouldn't be too surprised if the majority of those forks were created by an unwary click on the fork button when people might want to see the existing forks rather than create a new one. ;)

Answer (score 25):

After struggling with this for some time myself, I found that [vcpkg](https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg) does a very good job building gRPC C++ for Windows. Note the requirements are Window 7 or later and VS2015 Update 3 or later. Note that you can configure it the way you want it by using a triplet, e.g. .\vcpkg.exe install grpc --triplet x86-windows-static

Answer (score 10):

In order to install gRPC using vcpkg, launch a console in Windows and execute the following command,

1. `vcpkg install grpc:x64-windows`
2. `vcpkg install protobuf protobuf:x64-windows`
3. `vcpkg install protobuf[zlib] protobuf[zlib]:x64-windows`
4. `vcpkg integrate install`

Now we have everything we need, so let's try to generate the message and service interfaces from a proto file using the protoc compiler

If protoc is not available from your console, you might have to add it to your system env PATH. And it will be present in your `<vcpkg_install_path>\packages\protobuf_x64-windows\tools\protobuf` folder

Now copy the file to our project/proto folder and run the following commands from there

1. `protoc -I=. --cpp_out=. <yourprotofile>.proto`
2. `protoc -I=. --grpc_out=. --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc="<vcpkg_install_path>\packages\grpc_x64-windows\tools\grpc\grpc_cpp_plugin.exe" <your_protofile>.proto`

Now let's add content to our CMakeLists.txt file. Take the following code and copy it to our CMakeLists.txt file.

```
//  start  //

cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 3.1 )

project( grpc_example )

find_package(gRPC CONFIG REQUIRED)

find_package( Protobuf REQUIRED )


include_directories(<vcpkg_install_path>/buildtrees/protobuf/src/23fa7edd52-3ba2225d30.clean/src)

add_executable( server src/server.cpp proto/helloworld.grpc.pb.cc proto/helloworld.pb.cc)

add_executable( client src/client.cpp proto/helloworld.grpc.pb.cc proto/helloworld.pb.cc)

target_link_libraries( server PRIVATE gRPC::grpc++ gRPC::grpc++_reflection gRPC::gpr gRPC::grpc gRPC::grpc++ gRPC::grpc_cronet protobuf::libprotoc protobuf::libprotobuf protobuf::libprotobuf-lite )

target_link_libraries( client PRIVATE gRPC::grpc++ gRPC::grpc++_reflection gRPC::gpr gRPC::grpc gRPC::grpc++ gRPC::grpc_cronet protobuf::libprotoc protobuf::libprotobuf protobuf::libprotobuf-lite )

// end //
```

Now go to our project/build folder and issue the following command to generate a project using CMake. I'll be generating a Visual Studio 2015 solution here, but the choice is up to you.

1. `cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" ../ -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=<vcpkg_install_path>/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake`
2. `cmake build .`
3. `cmake --build . --config Release`

Now go to the Release folder, and run the server.exe and client.exe

Comment: Hi, is the cmake part necessary? I thought `vcpkg` provides me everything ready to be consumed in Visual Studio? I tried to skip the cmake part and now I'm stuck with linker errors: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68768805/lnk2001-and-lnk2019-for-grpc-installed-via-vcpkg?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: To answer my previous comment: No, this is not necessary. One can ommit the cmake part of your answer and use a MSBuild based project in VisualStudio (= a regular console cpp project). However, there's a linker error on MSBuild based projects that needs to be fixed that way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68768805/still-linker-errors-in-visualstudio-for-grpc-despite-autolink-vcpkg-enabled/68772745#68772745

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution I used to install and use grpc on windows...

GRPC C++...
    install...
        Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017 Version 15.6.4
        Git
        CMake 
        Chocolatey 
        Open git as admin
            Active State Perl
                choco install activeperl
            Go
                choco install golang
            yasm
                choco install yasm
                add C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\yasm\tools to PATH
            Ninja
                choco install ninja
    clone grpc sources including submodules...
        git clone --recursive -b v1.10.x https://github.com/grpc/grpc
        cd grpc
    cmake: Using Ninja (supports boringssl's assembly optimizations)...
        close git
        open Administrator: Command Prompt (shift+RC cmd and run as admin)
        cd C:\Users\aaron\repo\grpc
        md .build && cd .build
        call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64
        cmake .. -GNinja -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
        cmake --build .
        ninja install
    generating code...
        open visual studio and create new project
        turn off precompiled headers
            RC project -> Properties -> C/C++ -> Precompiled Headers
                Set Precompiled Header = "Not Using Precompiled Headers"
            Delete stdafx.h/.cpp
        add .proto file 
            RC Resource Files -> Add new -> Utility -> Text.txt
                name file with .proto extension
        write .proto file contents
        copy .proto to "C:\Program Files (x86)\grpc\bin"
        navigate to "C:\Users\aaron\repo\grpc\.build"
        copy grpc_cpp_plugin.exe to "C:\Program Files (x86)\grpc\bin"
        open Administrator: Command Prompt
            cd C:\Program Files (x86)\grpc\bin
            protoc -I . --grpc_out=. --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=grpc_cpp_plugin.exe cid_service.proto
                Generates cid_service.grpc.pb.cc/.h
            protoc -I . --cpp_out=. cid_service.proto
                Generates cid_service.pb.cc/.h
        copy files to VS project and add them to Header Files/Source Files

Answer (score 2):

This helped a lot thank you for making this. I used this by extracting the zip, cd in the folder and with

```
git clone -b v1.2.0 https://github.com/grpc/grpc

git submodule update --init
```

Install pthreads to visual studios VC\include(.h), lib(.lib) and bin(.dll)

run nuget restore (foreach .sln file to get dependencies)

```
nuget restore grpc\vsprojects\grpc.sln

nuget restore grpc\vsprojects\grpc_protoc_plugins.sln

nuget restore grpc\third_party\protobuf\cmake\build\solution\protobuf.sln
```

Fix grpc\src\cpp\server\ server_builder.cc

```
int num_frequently_polled_cqs = sync_server_cqs->size();
```

Change int to size_t in line 273, int num...(as above)

Run grpc_build.bat, next goto grpc_helloworld folder and run 
test_protoc.bat, open grpc_helloworld.sln, running build should     execute nuget automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the instructions from the BUILDING.md. You can check it out here as well: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/BUILDING.md

- I cloned the grpc repo with `git clone -b v1.55.0 https://github.com/grpc/grpc`
- The command `git submodule update --init` **failed**, I had to delete /third_party/opencensus-proto manually
- I needed to run `git rm --cached third_party/opencensus-proto` this step may be not required when the directory is deleted before running git submodule, then I was able to get the missing submodules
- I used Visual Studio using `cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 17 2022"`

Then I was able to follow the further instructions for Windows